# Screenshot of video

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am making an application where I want to take a screenshot. In foreground I am running some videos which are looping, also I have a background picture set. The problem is, when I take the screenshot, I get the background picture and not the picture of the video that runs.

```
            try {
                // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
                String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/app/" + fname + ".jpg";

                // create bitmap screen capture
                View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);

                File imageFile = new File(mPath);

                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                int quality = 90;
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                Log.d("MainActivity","TakeScreenshot SUCCESS");

                //openScreenshot(imageFile);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
                Log.d("MainActivity","TakeScreenshot ERROR ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Does anybody know how to take a snapshot of the video running on screen?

Comment: can you mention what view you are using to show the video?

Comment: I am using WebView for video